# Convert Store Data to Object with Defined Key Name ExtJS

Tags: javascript, object, extjs, key, store

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362237/how-to-get-array-of-objects-from-store-in-extjs-4-2-and-send-it-to-server-side) answer, I want to convert store data to object and defined the key value as well. Here's my related code :

```
var recordArray = {};
var paramArray = [];

store.each(function(record){
    recordArray.comment = record.get("comment");
    recordArray.datecreated = record.get("datecreated");
    paramArray.push(recordArray);
});

console.log(Ext.encode(paramArray));
```

But the printed out is only last data from store, with sum matches with data sum. Suppose I have 2 data from list view like this :

```
[{comment: a, datecreated:1-2-1999}, {comment: b, datecreated:2-2-1999}]
```

The print out :

```
[{comment: b, datecreated:2-2-1999}, {comment: b, datecreated:2-2-1999}]
```

What I want, of course, the paramArray contains every object of listView, not just a same one. Any ideas? Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
var paramArray = [];
store.each(function(record){
    var recordArray = {};
    recordArray.comment = record.get("comment");
    recordArray.datecreated = record.get("datecreated");
    paramArray.push(recordArray);
});
```

In your code, you are overwriting the values in the original recordArray object instead of creating a new object everytime and since objects are passed by reference in JavaScript, the original recordArray reference at paramArray[0] also gets modified.